# Simple dlookup in access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a query created in access

```
CSAT(Table1) 
date, login_name, score
```

.

```
Roster(Table2) tCAM is same as login_name
tCAM, AGENTNAME
```

This is a append query to append this to a 3rd table called

```
Csat_all (Table)
date, login_name, Agent, Score
```

How can i use ***dlookup*** to fill the ***Agent*** column in **Csat_all**

I am trying to use this type:

```
name:  DLookup ( [Csat]![login_name] , [Roster]![AGENTNAME ] )
```

When i RUN this i get a message box:

```
Enter parameter value
Roster!AGENTNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

The DLookup syntax goes like this:

```
LookUpName: DLookup("[FieldName]", "[TableName]", "[SearchFieldOfTableName] = '" & [FieldWithValue] & "'")
```